# Fuzzy Record Linkage of Spatial Datasets

Tags: dataset, spatial, data-imputation, fuzzy, record-linkage

I have two datasets describing real-estate properties

Dataset 1 describes building characteristics; it includes the location of the entrance to the building along with building descriptions and demographics;

```
Longitude     Latitude          Quality Index       Age of building (years) (.....hundreds)
13.3166960844 52.4720710276     1                    5
13.3724798666 52.5319328086     4                    11
13.3810401552 52.53146403       5                    12
(.... millions)
```

Dataset 2 describes real estate transactions; it includes locations, transaction price and date

```
Longitude     Latitude          Transaction Date     Transaction Price
13.3943043389 52.5342395928     01.05.12             100000
13.3946001820 52.53146403       10.03.10             324500   
13.3927096776 52.532384714      04.12.05             400000
(..... millions)
```

I would like to join the two datasets, so each record in dataset 2 has the corresponding data from dataset 1, but there are several issues -

1. The location in dataset 1 is very accurate, but the one in dataset 2 is less accurate and may be 10-1000 meters off the actual location
2. The properties in dataset 1, along with those in dataset 2, should be able to explain at least 90% of the variance in the transaction price, if you could only match the records in the two datasets

I heard there are good record linkage algorithms out there - but have no experience with them. Otherwise, I am quite experienced with (geo-) regression techniques. But frankly, I have no idea where I should even start.